# How to create completely accessible tables using div structure in html ADA

Tags: html, html-table, nvda, jaws-screen-reader

I need the following table to be readable using arrow keys by NVDA and Jaws :

```html
<div class="maintable" role="grid" tabindex="0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">Test 1</div>
    <div class="column">Test 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">Test 3</div>
    <div class="column">Test 4</div>
  </div>enter code here

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">Test 5</div>
    <div class="column">Test 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Its readable using `role="grid"`, but in one shot not using arrow keys.